# Show that $Z^n$ for a nonnengative integer $n$ is normal family

Tags: complex-analysis

Show that the function $z^n$ for a nonnegative integer $n$ form a normal family in $|z|<1$ ,also in $|z|>1$ but not in the region that contains a point on the unit circle.

I am working on this problem from Complex Analysis by Lars Ahlfors and I need help.
This is what I am thinking, And it's a bit vague. Since the family $Z^n, n\geq 1$ converges for all $z$ within the unit circle, Any subsequence of $z^n$ converges. on the other hand, considering $|z|>1$ I don't know how to approach it.
Any assistance will be appreciated.
Thank you

Answer (score 2):

> A family $\mathcal{F}$ of holomorphic functions on a region $\Omega$ is normal if and only if $\mathcal{F}$ is uniformly bounded on compact subsets.

In your case $z^n$ is uniformly bounded in the unit disc, and in $|z|>1$ every sequence contains a subsequence which tends uniformly to $\infty$. We also consider this latter case normal. See Ahlfors Definition 3:

> A family of analytic functions is normal if every sequence contains a subsequence converging on compact subsets or a subsequence that tends to $\infty$ uniformly

Can you see what happens when $|z|=1$?

Comment: I think when $|z|=1$ it implies  there is a subsequence e.g  $(-1)^n$ that diverges so it is not a normal family.

Comment: Here is the answer for $|z|=1$. Suppose $U$ is an open set containing at least one point $a$ with $|a|=1$. This open set contains points with $|Z|>1$ as well as ponits wit $|z|<1$. If $\{z^{n}\}$ is normal there is a subsequence $\{z^{n_k}\}$ which converges uniformly on compact sets to a continuous function or to $\infty$. However  $\{|z^{n_k}|\} \to \infty$ if $|z|>1$ and to 0 if $|z|<1$. This is a contradiction.